# Hypeledger Fabric for ARM - exited with code 159

Tags: docker-compose, raspberry-pi, arm, hyperledger

Installed the hyperledger fabric on the Raspberry Pi by following the instructions in the following URL

https://www.polarsparc.com/xhtml/Hyperledger-ARM-Setup.html

Not got the desired output 3 and 4 however there is no error displayed when use --platform linux/arm64 in the command.

While running the following command

```
$docker-compose -f docker/compose-test-net.yaml up
 Starting c21bcb2ae62d_peer0.org2.example.com ... done
 Starting 4424856e09bb_peer0.org1.example.com ... done
 Starting orderer.example.com                 ... done
 Starting cli                                 ... done
 Attaching to 4424856e09bb_peer0.org1.example.com, c21bcb2ae62d_peer0.org2.example.com, orderer.example.com, cli
 4424856e09bb_peer0.org1.example.com exited with code 159
 orderer.example.com exited with code 159
 c21bcb2ae62d_peer0.org2.example.com exited with code 159
 cli exited with code 159
```

It exits immediately with the same error code (159) every time.

Comment: It is resolved. The version of the docker needs 64-bit Operating System however the system was having 32-bit OS